# how to give html an id to the link

Tags: jquery

How to give an id for each page when you click on page number, For example:

```
www.example.com
```

When I press on page number 4, the link becomes `www.example.com#page4`
and the page jumps to top.

### Code on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tkmm0n6w/)

#### HTML:

```
<div class="full">
  <table class="flat-table flat-table-2" width="70%" style="margin:auto;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>numbers</th>
        <th>address</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="page1">
      <tr>
        <td>1-3</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="page2" class="hidden">
      <tr>
        <td>2-3</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="page3"  class="hidden">
      <tr>
        <td>3-3</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">test</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="footer-pop">
    <a href= "#" data-id="page3"class="pages">3</a>
    <a href= "#" data-id="page2"class="pages">2</a>
    <a href="#" data-id="page1"class="pages">1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To add #page4 to the url, then your anchor tag needs to look like this `<a href="#page4">test</a>`

Comment: yeah , but it doesn't jump to top :)

Comment: Yes to jump to the top you can use bencripps answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery you can use the `animate` function to manipulate the scroll position. Here is the function that handles that functionality.

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {

    $('html, body').animate({

        scrollTop: 0

    }, 500);

});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tkmm0n6w/2/)

Comment: Great , your answer helped me with the jump to top , but when i give the page anchor tag , it's appeare on the url only , when i copy it and put it into browser , it's redircet me to the first page :(
check here
http://ghadaalsaman.com/poertylist.html

Comment: And what do you want to happen?

Comment: it should send me to the wanted page with it's anchor tag , not redirect me to the the page number 1